# Helm chart release github action fails with 422

Tags: kubernetes-helm, github-actions

I'm trying to release [this branch](https://github.com/linux-training-group-1/asset-registry-config/tree/gh-pages) of my helm repo. But the charts release gh-action fails with 422. How can I fix this issue?

The error message: https://github.com/linux-training-group-1/asset-registry-config/runs/4341586935?check_suite_focus=true
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue myself. It was with the name I put to the Helm Chart in Chart.yaml.
Apparently the chart release GitHub action takes the release tag from the chart name. Therefore Chart name cannot have spaces in it.